# Video playback with Qt: Phonon or libVLC

Tags: windows, qt, libvlc, phonon

I'm trying to get [libVLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/libvlc.html) working with my [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) C++ application but I am wondering if I should be using [Phonon](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/phonon-overview.html) for simplicity.
I read about Phonon-VLC ([VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)) which lead me to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon_%28KDE%29#Backends where VLC is mentioned as backend.
I'm confused: which is based on which?
Are there any advantages using one or the other? Probably Phonon is easier to use as backends are chosen cross-platformy while libVLC integration requires more work.

Comment: [Qt says](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtmobility-1.2.0/multimedia.html): "QtMultimediaKit is the recommended API to build multimedia applications using Qt. The Phonon API is no longer recommended."

Comment: You should also have a look at the library [vlc-qt](https://github.com/ntadej/vlc-qt) which would provide you an OO interface while lowering the cost of LibVLC integration.